# Sharepoint application working , Server Out Of Memory. There is no memory on the server to run your program

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, moss2007-security

Server Out Of Memory.

There is no memory on the server to run your program. Please contact your administrator with this problem.

```
<nativehr>0x8007000e</nativehr><nativestack>stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000140E10) at 0x000007FEE7F10E10
owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000A24D4) at 0x000007FEE81924D4
mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002BB647) at 0x000007FEF657B647
Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000F7E96) at 0x000007FEE9037E96
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AB0BE6) at 0x000007FEEDFD0BE6
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001A80CD7) at 0x000007FEEDFA0CD7
</nativestack>
```

Comment: well... it seems like your server is out of memory. Out of RAM. You should add more RAM.

Comment: if you are not able to add more RAM, Then try to minimize your RAM consumption, close your some application and then try ...hope it may work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try recycling your the app-pool which hosts your app. If that helps you might wanna consider scheduling an recycle. It might not be the app itself that eats your memory, it could be something else and when the app is trying to run there is not enough ram for it to do that. You could try an iisreset if you understand what that does and can run it in that environment, i'm guessing it's not your dev env. we're talking about. Have you checked your code for undisposed objects? You can do so with [SPDisposeCheck](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck). Hope it helps.